# getInstance() doesn't work with other location than us-central1 in Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save user credentials to Firebase Realtime Database. However, when I execute the program, the DB does not update. I have configured the Firebase setup correctly as Authentication and Storage (both Firebase) are working.

`build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    // Firebase SDK setup
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')

    // Declare the dependency for the Firebase library
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package=<NAME>>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
      ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The registration class (MWE):

```
class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var selectedPhotoUri: Uri? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Register UI
        register_button_register.setOnClickListener {
            performRegister()
        }
    }

    // Register user credentials
    private fun performRegister() {
        val email = email_editText_register.text.toString()
        val password = password_editText_register.text.toString()

        // Firebase Authentication - WORKING
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                uploadImageToFirebaseStorage()
            }
    }

    // Upload selected photo to Firebase Storage - WORKING
    private fun uploadImageToFirebaseStorage() {
        if(selectedPhotoUri == null)    return

        val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$filename")

        ref.putFile(selectedPhotoUri!!)

        ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
            saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(it.toString())
        }
    }

    // Save user associated credentials to Firebase Database - NOT WORKING
    private fun saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(profileImageURL: String) {
        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
        val ref = Firebase.database.getReference("/users/$uid")
        val user = User(uid, username_editText_register.text.toString(), profileImageURL)

        ref.setValue(user)
    }
}

// User credentials to be saved
class User(val uid: String, val username: String, val profileImageURL: String)
```

The `saveUserToFirebaseDatabase()` method does not get executed? I have checked `logcat` after inserting `onSuccessListener` and `onFailureListener` statements, however no error or debug information is highlighted. The app. pushes the image to storage but the DB is not updated. It remains empty. The workflow is as:

```
- Authenticate user by email and password. - WORKING
- Save profile image in Storage. - WORKING
- Save profile identifier, username, and image in DB. - NOT WORKING
```

Firebase DB rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

I tried changing the hierarchy but that did not work either:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid ?: ""
val ref = Firebase.database.getReference("/users/$uid")
val user = User(uid, username_edittext_register.text.toString(), profileImageUrl)
   
ref.child("users").child(uid).setValue(user)
```

I have read the Firebase documentation and everything seems to be in place. I also disabled my firewall but that did not work either. Can someone point out the problem here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a complete listener to the `.setValue(user)` to see if something goes wrong? Besides that, what is your database location?

Comment: Yes I have. None of the listeners are even getting triggered in the `saveUserToFirebaseDatabase()` method, which is suspicious. The DB location is 'europe-west1' as I am based in London.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a reference to a Firebase Realtime Database other than the (default) "us-central1", for instance "europe-west1", you must pass the database URL to the [getInstance()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#getInstance(java.lang.String)) method.

For "us-central1" there is no need for doing that, you can simply call the "getInstance()" method without passing any arguments.

For more info, please check the official documentation regarding Realtime Database locations:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#rtdb-locations

As an alternative solution, you can download an up-to-date `google-services.json` from the Firebase Console and add it to your app. If the correct URL of the location is in there, the SDK will read it from there when you call `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()` without passing any arguments.