# How to read data from Firebase Database? - Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a game, if the player wins, then the victory is added to the database. How can I read the data from here?

[image]

and paste here:

[image]

I read the player's name in a different way, which cannot be repeated with victories and defeats.

Comment: Use the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) to learn how to read data in Firebase.  If you don't make an attempt and show us where you are stuck, there's not much we can do to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to read the data under the `jjjj` node, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference nameRef = db.child("players").child("jjjj");
nameRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            String loses = snapshot.child("loses").getValue(Long.class);
            String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String wins = snapshot.child("wins").getValue(Long.class);
            Log.d("TAG", loses + "/" + name + "/" + wins);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
3/jjjj/4
```

Things to notice:

- Always create a reference that points to the node that you want to read.
- If your database is located in another lcoation than the default, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795058/save-android-user-credentials-to-firebase-database-kotlin/) out.

Answer (score 0):

**use this method**

> This is the method of fetching data from the firebase realtime database

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    reference.child("players").child(name).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```