# Getting region error when integating firebase realtime database in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting this error in flutter project when trying to integrate `Realtime Database in flutter.

```
Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://xxx-xxx-xxxx-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app
```

Options that I have already tried

1. Invalidate caches/ restart
2. Updating my google-services.json file through flutterfire configure
3. Directly referencing to the database url

Comment: Have you tried to [specify the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795058/save-android-user-credentials-to-firebase-database-kotlin/)?

Comment: Yes, That finally resolved the issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Instancing the Firebase object with specifying URL.

```
val mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://firebase-appname.southeast1.firebasedatabase.app").reference
```

> FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("firebase-url").reference