# Having trouble with connecting firebase realtime database to my app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to connect firebase realtime database to my app. I watched many youtube about this and tried the same way of videos but it doesn't work for me. Below is the step I followed.

**Make empty project** >> **add 'android:exported = "true"' on manifest file** (without this my app gets an error while building)  >> **go tools and select firebase** >> **select Realtime Database** >> **click 'get started with realtime database [KOTLIN]'** >> Following the guideline, I've **connected my app to Firebase** and **Added the Realtime Database to my app** like below image
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoMc9.png)

After that, at firebase console, the firebase project showed that my app is connected and then I created a realtime database. Below is how it looks.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No2lG.png)

The security rules are test mode. And then I tried to insert a data to the database. Below is the code.

```kotlin
    val testData = 110
    private lateinit var database : DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn1)

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("testing")

            database.setValue(testData).addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(this,"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }.addOnFailureListener{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

My purpose was simply saving the value of **testData** on the database and toasting a message when I press the button (**btn**). But if I do it, Nothing happens to my database and also the app doesn't toast any message. What can I do for it?

project level `gradle` file

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.31"
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
         }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

app level `gradle` file

```kotlin
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lotterynumber.firebase"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

*When I Debug app, there is an warning that says '**w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:**'. Could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Is any of the onSuccess or onFailure even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo It seems nothing is triggered. It should toast a message if one is triggered but the app doesn't toast even the fail message.

Comment: Then are you sure you have an internet connection on the device? Besides that, what is the location of the database?

Comment: @AlexMamo Oh. I don't know why, but my AVD's wifi is not connected with the notice 'Networks Unavailable'. I'll handle this problem first. Thank you! by the way the location of the database is us-central1.

Comment: If it's `us-central1`, then [there is no need to specify that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795058/save-android-user-credentials-to-firebase-database-kotlin/).

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you so much! It was the network issue. After connecting network, it worked very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If none of the onSuccess() or onFailure() methods are triggered, and your database location is us-central1, then most likely the reason is the lack of an internet connection. Establish a connection on your emulator and it will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 btn.setOnClickListener {
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("testing")
     .
     .
     .}
```

I think it will solve your problem